# Error in unit testing Ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

The below code returns true if sum of triplets is equal to a given number

```
class triplet
def three_sum_fast(ary, sum)
  ary.sort!

  (0..ary.length - 3).each do |i|
    front = ary[i]
    start_index = i + 1
    back_index = ary.length - 1

    while(start_index < back_index) do
      start = ary[start_index]
      back = ary[back_index]

      if (front + start + back) > 0
        back_index -= 1
      else
        start_index += 1
      end

       if front + start + back == sum
          return true
          break
      end

    end

  end
  false
end

end
```

The below code is the test file

```
require  "test/unit"
require  "triplet.rb"

class Test < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_trip
        num=triplet.new
        num.three_sum_fast({1,3,4,5,6,7},14)
        assert_equal (expected,true)
    end
end
```

The errors found are :

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
    num.three_sum_fast({1,3,4,5,6,7},14)
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
    assert_equal (expected,true)
```

Comment: brackets denote an array, not curly braces.

Comment: You class name should be capitalized (i.e. `Triplet`).

Comment: @orde  No change in the error

Comment: @Stefan: Agreed.  Should have been...errr...must be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Class name

Class names are constants and therefore must start with a capital letter:

```
class Triplet
  # ...
end
```

And in your test:

```
num = Triplet.new
```

#### Array literal

An array is created via `[` and `]`, whereas a hash is created via `{` and `}`, i.e.

```
num.three_sum_fast([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 14)
```

#### Method invocation

There is an erroneous space in the next line:

```
assert_equal (expected,true)
#           ^
#           that one is wrong
```

It has to be:

```
assert_equal(expected, true)
#                     ^
#                     that one is okay
```

#### Undefined variable

Even with the faulty space removed, the line does not work, because `expected` is an undefined variable. You have to *assign* it, before you can use it:

```
expected = num.three_sum_fast([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 14)
assert_equal(expected, true)
```

This works, but `expected` is a misnomer. `true` is the *expected* value, whereas the method's result is the *actual* value. So it should be:

```
actual = num.three_sum_fast([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 14)
assert_equal(true, actual)
```

or simply:

```
assert_equal(true, num.three_sum_fast([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 14))
```